# iMacro : Need to get rid of somethings from EXTRACT

Tags: jquery, imacros

This is my HTML :

```
div class="shopee-image-gallery__optional-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cf.shopee.co.th/file/034df183f358eea91957ea952cdeccc7_tn&quot;); outline: 1px solid blue;"> /div
```

this is what I get from EXTRACT by

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}}  TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:shopee-image-gallery__optional-image&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
```

What I need is:

```
https://cf.shopee.co.th/file/034df183f358eea91957ea952cdeccc7
```

What should I do with iMacro please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
SET url EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/&quot;(.+)&quot;/)[1].split('_')[0];")
```